# How to store multiple lists using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, list, database-design

I want to allow users to create multiple lists be it of their favorite items or whatever, so far this is what I've come up with.

I have four tables

table 1 holds user id and info

table 2 holds item id and info

table 3 holds list id and info

table three will hold

user_id, list_id ,item_id

So basically i have two questions,
 1. Is this the ideal table setup for this?

2.How would i insert each item from the users created list,would a foreach do it? Or is there a way mysql allows multiple inserts?

Answer (score 1):

How about 3 tables:

table 1 - user id and info

table 2 - item id and info, user id

table 3 - list id and info, item id (considering item id is used to reference this table)

Multiple inserts example:

```
INSERT INTO USERS
  (user_id, fname, lname)
VALUES
  (100, 'First Name 1', 'Last Name 1'),
  (101, 'First Name 2', 'Last Name 2'),
  (102, 'First Name 3', 'Last Name 3');
```

Comment: The reason i put lists into its own table is so that every time a user adds an item i dont have to insert list info for example, if a user has 5 items in a list each of the 5 entries would include the list name and list description

Comment: lists is a different table (table 3). If you want to add records only to table USER (user dependent), then it should be have item_id as a field in it. Hence, you can refer the ITEMS table from that, and also LISTS.